# Converting Crystal reports to SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Basically i converted this crystal report formula "if ucas({?Trade Buy or Sell}) = "Trade Buy" then "IOSW_BUY_01" else if ucase({?Trade Buy or Sell})="Trade Sell" then IOSW_SELL_02."

to SSRS -IIF(Fields!TradeBuyorSell.Value="Trade Buy","IOSW_BUY_01", 
    IIF(Fields!TradeBuyorSell.Value="Trade Sell","IOSW_SELL_02"))
but I am getting the below error message

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> [rsCompilerErrorInExpression]The value expression for the textrun 'TradeBuyorSell.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0] contains an
>   error :[BC30455]Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart'of
>   Public Function IIF(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object,
>   FalsePart As Object) As Object'
>    Please assist this is very urgent

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you have this error is because the Crystal report formula is not well written. In Crystal you can have formula like "if condition then true-part", the false-part can be left out. Crystal will automatically handle the default. But in SSRS, it is more strict, IIF cannot omit the false part.